# Add toolbar button to TFS' "My Work" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar

I find I go to the My Work pane inside the Team Explorer frequently, but I haven't found a way to get there in one click. I can create a shortcut key for the command `TeamFoundationContextMenus.Commands.GoToMyWork` and that works, but I'm looking for something I can click on a toolbar.

So specifically, my question is: where in the toolbar customization "Add Command" list does this option exist? There are several categories and many items in each, and I haven't found a way to search, only scroll.

More generally, and if the option doesn't exist, is there a way to use the command name in the keyboard shortcut customization to create a toolbar button for that command?

Answer (score 0):

For a toolbar you can add commands only from the existing VS menu.

For additional commands, you can create an intermediate [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) command `DTE.ExecuteCommand("TeamFoundationContextMenus.Commands.GoToMyWork")` and then add this **VCmd.Command01** command to a toolbar.

Comment: I was looking for something built-in to Visual Studio. I thought I was just missing something, as it looks like it should be an option. The other three TFS tasks I do regularly are available (explorer, pending, history). I'd rather click twice than install a third party add-on that would then require further custom configuration.